# separar registros a partir de campo com valores separados por ponto e virgula no MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados mysql, tabela GRUPOS e PRODUTOS.

**GRUPOS**

```
+-----------------+
| grupoid         |
+-----------------+
| 1               |
| 2               |
| 3               |
+-----------------+
```

**PRODUTOS**

```
+-----------------+
|   id |  grupoid |
+-----------------+
|   1  |  1;2;3   |
+-----------------+
```

Preciso fazer um select e separa cada grupo por linha como o exemplo abaixo.

**Resultado do select**

```
+-----------------+
| produto |grupoid|
+-----------------+
|    1    |  1    |
|    1    |  2    |
|    1    |  3    |
+-----------------+
```

Desde já obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: pesquise a função `SUBSTRING_INDEX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Consegui encontrar a solução aqui, segue link [Divisão de valores separados por vírgula no MySQL](https://www.sisense.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql/)

Então, a minha query ficou assim:

```
  SELECT gg.descricao,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.grupos, ';', g.grupoid), 
    ';', 
    -1
  ) as grupo
FROM produtos AS p
JOIN grupos AS g ON CHAR_LENGTH(p.grupos) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(p.grupos, ';', '')) >= g.grupoid - 1
INNER JOIN grupos_imeis as gi ON gi.grupoid = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.grupos, ';', g.grupoid), 
    ';', 
    -1
  ))
INNER JOIN grupos AS gg ON gg.grupoid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.grupos, ';', g.grupoid), 
    ';', 
    -1
  )
```